# opencv-3.3.0 Stops compiling at 58%

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm compiling opencv for Rasbian Stretch, running on the Pi 3b.
It compiled all the way to 58% before outputting this error.
Anybody familiar with the error and how to correct it?

[58%]Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_datasets.so
CMakeFiles/opencv_datasets.dir/src/gr_chalearn.cpp.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: id returned 1 exit status
modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/opencv_datasets.dir/build.make:858: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_datasets.so.3.3.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_datasets.so.3.3.] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:14481: recipe for target 'modules/datasets/CmakeFiles/opencv_datasets.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/datasets/CMakeFiles/opencv_datasets.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Was this error ever solved?

Comment: @TanMath I solved this issue by downloading opencv-3.4 and running make with -j4

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by downloading opencv-3.4 and running make with `-j4`

Answer (score 0):

Building OpenCV binaries on officially supported Ubuntu/Linux based operating systems has always been a little more troublesome than normal images. One of the core reasons is the visual graphics (mostly, but not limited to) used by these distributions are different than general ones. You'll find some similar errors while installing it on LXDE based Ubuntu distributions, for the same reason. I spotted different errors for the same method on Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome, Ubuntu 18.04 LXDE, Ubuntu 16.04 LXDE, and Raspbian OS. Having said that, there are always solutions available.

Please check this [link](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-16-04/) for libraries required. Make sure you have all the repositories added which are required for installation. You must look extremely carefully for these libraries:

1. `libgsteramer1.0-dev`, `libgstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dev` & `libgstreamer1.0-base-dev`.
2. `libprotobuf-dev` & `protobuf-compliler`
3. `libatlas-base-dev`
4. `libjasper-dev` (this one for wheezy, you'll need to enable repository)
5. `libfaac-dev`

These libraries will be required and a test will run on them during CMake. Some of them have a lot of dependency issues like `libpng-dev` and `libtheora-dev`. If you can paste the initial part of your CMake build, we can pin-point those libraries.